# Не подгружается Android Layout в Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, android-sdk, android, monodevelop, visual-studio-2012

Установил Xamarin. Запускаю через Моно - все работает, рабочий слой (layout) - подгружается. Запускаю в VS12 - пишет, что layout не загружен т.к не найден. В чем проблема ? Как исправить ?

Comment: Разработка Android под VS12 это путь героя. Рекомендую выкинуть Mono/VS12 и перейти под Eclipse/IDEA.